# inconsistency between @@global.gtid_executed and mysql.gtid_executed

Tags: mysql

Starting MySQL 5.7.6, mysql.gtid_executed is supposed to keep track of all gtids executed.

However in MySQL 5.7.14, I am seeing a scenario as shown below:

```
mysql> select @@global.gtid_executed;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@global.gtid_executed                                                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cd5cd102-6586-0742-6f26-5b4c4c17d44d:4294967296:8589934592-8589939092 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mysql.gtid_executed;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Can this discrepancy be explained?

Comment: This is in steady state after a fresh start of a MySQL instance

Comment: Which version is Master?

Comment: the master is on 5.7.14

Answer (score 1):

mysql.gtid_executed is an internal table used to support some specific use cases; it's not meant to be monitored/used like @@global.gtid_executed (and other ways to access it, such as performance_schema.global_variables).

And it's only updated at certain times, which is what you were seeing. You can read more about it [here](http://mysqlhighavailability.com/mysql-5-7-store-gtids-in-table/).

Answer (score 0):

The content of the table `mysql.gtid_executed` is not updated real-time but rather only under certain circumstances, like a stop of mysql or when a binlog file is rotated.